# DIV moves when I put text in it

Tags: css, html, text

I spent some time creating a pedigree out of div layers on [this site](http://dev4.peeknpoke.co.uk/dogs/jester.php) and I got it all nicely aligned.

But when I put text in it, whether just in the div or in p tags, it moves the div layer down significantly.

It doesn't seem to add any margin or padding or anything else I can see while inspecting the element, and it doesn't seem to be affecting the grandchild div layers.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfjkLze3/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="pedigree">
    <div id="parentwrap">
        <div class="parent">test</div>
    </div>
    <div id="childwrap">
        <div class="child">
            <p>Am. Ch. Kenai's Aldebaran</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <p>pAm. Ch. Santa Clara Del Viento</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grandchildwrap">
        <div class="grandchild">Am. Can. Ch. Ryzann's Eclipse at Kenai</div>
        <div class="grandchild">Am. Ch. Timber Ridge's Abi of Kenai</div>
        <div class="grandchild">Am. Ch. Sky Run Gavril Virtual Zip JC</div>
        <div class="grandchild">Am. Can. Ch. Tazeb's Zena</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pedigree {
    position: relative;
    width: 584px;
    height: 204px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
#parentwrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    width:auto;
    height: 205px;
}
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 190px;
    height: 202px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#childwrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 205px;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
    width: 190px;
    height: 95px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#grandchildwrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 205px;
}
.grandchild {
    position: relative;
    width: 190px;
    height: 46px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.parent, .child, .grandchild {
    -moz-border-radius: 35px;
    border-radius: 35px;
```

Comment: See [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Not related, but the copy on your site is riddled with spelling/grammar mistakes. Remember to fix this too!

Comment: point taken will add code

Comment: Will it change anything if you remove `height` from div `#pedigree`?

Comment: lee - yeah this is what happens when you let your girlfriend with dyslexia do the content adding! thanks for the interest :)

Comment: @user1595170 :: 27 Errors, 1 warning :: can you validate your markups first.

Comment: Isolate this down two the smallest possible set of markup/css etc.  Often that will enlighten you, and you get to learn with a more focused set.  As an aside, from my limited experience it is likely something inside something else that is larger than the container.

Comment: morpheus - No apparently not.  mark - I thought it may  be somethign inside something but i dont see what.  I have three containers aide by side with the smaller divs inside.  and i put text straight into the div layer <div>text</div> and it breaks.  the only thing Ive put inside it is text and with my test text it doesnt seem to make any difference how much text i put in.  I tried p tags to no difference.  milche - will do thanks for pointing that out! - on review these are mostly no alts which I wont do until I have finalise which images are going to be used

Comment: fiddle of the example:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/A8b3E/

Comment: Just a thanks again to all those who commented, I will take everything on board and learn html and how to make more useful help posts!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Adding the text creates a baseline for the #parentwrap div, so the div gets aligned to that. Without the text, there's no baseline so the div takes a fallback layout mode.

To fix, set add `#parentwrap { vertical-align:top; }`

Comment: i did wonder if it might be an alignment problem but i didnt understand why it would be ( hence asking rather than guessing - better to understand why) not that im sure why it creates a baseline there by default, seems pretty useless but that has indeed fixed my problem so thank you very much indeed. It really is great to have such a wonderful community of people.

Comment: @Alohci can you explain, or give me a link that explains "baseline."

Comment: @Nix - It does indeed. The precise rules for aligning to the baseline, which is the default is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align. Note in particular it says "baseline: Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. **If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with the parent's baseline.**"

Comment: Thanks.  I think it helps us developers that are aspiring designers ;)