# adding content to the div make it move down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following page layout and when I add `div` with class `card` to the `div` with class `page` entire `div` moves down.

If I remove the `div` with the class `card` then every thing comes back to normal.

what is the problem and to fix this?

code:  https://jsfiddle.net/5t0ybLn2/

```css
/*******************page layout**************************/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.sidebarcontainer {
  width: 250PX;
  height: 6000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.innersidebarcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 243px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mainpage {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  height: 6000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.footer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #031003;
}


/***************end of pagelayout******************/

.card {
  width: 250px;
  /*height: 400px;*/
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer">
      <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
        <div class="sidebar">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
    -->
    <div class="mainpage">
      <div class="page">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="http://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/archive/winsupersite.com/content/content/143119/pr8.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span>This is name of book</span>
            <span>this is author</span>
            <span>this is price</span>
            <span>this is rating</span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854725/div-moves-when-i-put-text-in-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DIV moves when I put text in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854725/div-moves-when-i-put-text-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the `display: flex` property to your `container` class to make it work.

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  display: flex;
}
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5t0ybLn2/1/)

Comment: what was the actual problem?

Comment: By default (if you don't change it) the display property is set to "inline". This will arrange the children under eachother, instead of next to each other. 
if you change it to flexbox, it will assume a flexdirection of "row", witch puts the children next to each other

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```css
/*******************page layout**************************/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.sidebarcontainer {
  width: 250PX;
  height: 6000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.innersidebarcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 243px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mainpage {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  height: 6000px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.footer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #031003;
}


/***************end of pagelayout******************/

.card {
  width: 250px;
  /*height: 400px;*/
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer">
      <div class="innersidebarcontainer">
        <div class="sidebar">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
    -->
    <div class="mainpage">
      <div class="page">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="http://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/archive/winsupersite.com/content/content/143119/pr8.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span>This is name of book</span>
            <span>this is author</span>
            <span>this is price</span>
            <span>this is rating</span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```