# Why does this row shift down wen I click on one of its boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code https://jsfiddle.net/wLyux9un/

```js
const PLAYER_TOKEN = 'X';
const COMPUTER_TOKEN = '0';


$(document).ready(function() {
  const grid = [
    [' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ']
  ];

  $('.col').click(function() {

    $(this).html(PLAYER_TOKEN);


  });


});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 2px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>



<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tictak.css">




<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

  </div>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

  </div>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

  </div>



  <div>
    <button id="restart">Restart</button>
  </div>








  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="tictak.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Why when i click on the boxes the row is moving down?

```
.col{

    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    height:70px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:2px;
    font-size:30px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-top:20px;   
}
```

Comment: As a provisional solution, use `<div class="col">&nbsp;</div>` instead of `<div class="col"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854725/div-moves-when-i-put-text-in-it). Add a `vertical-align: middle;` to your `.col` class. A `vertical-align` of `top` or `bottom` would also work, as long as it is applied to the parent container. W3 has a very good explanation of why this works [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)